# Close window with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple code:

```
<div id="rss">
    <div id="close">
        <a href="#" ><img alt="close"src="images/close.png" width="16" height="12"/> </a>
    </div>
    <ul><a href="fill.php"><?php  echo $rss['rss']; ?></a></ul>
</div>
```

I want when someone click image `<a href="#" ><img alt="close"src="images/close.png" width="16" height="12"/> </a>` entire `<div id="rss"></div>` would close. I'm looking at javascript function `onclick="window.close()`, but it looks is not what I need. Help, someone?

Comment: What do you mean by "close"? Does `document.getElementById('rss').style.display="none";` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.close will close an actual browser window. It sounds like you want the div

```
<div id="rss"></div>
```

to hide instead.

As was pointed out in comments you can do this with the following javascript.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('rss').style.display='none'; return false;" >
  <img alt="close"src="images/close.png" width="16" height="12"/> 
</a>
```

Note that we use single quotes in the javascript so that it doesn't interfere with syntax of html. Also note that we return false which prevents the clicked link from navigating.